# Mongo Date query with limited hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoDB query to get data for a week (14, Feb -- 21, Feb) but between 9-5.
How we can achieve this!
Thanks in Advance.

> collection.aggregate(
> [
> {
> $match: {
> date: range...
> }
> },
> ]
> ).pretty()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$expr` and `$hour`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "date": {
    $gte: new Date("2023-02-14"),
    $lt: new Date("2023-02-22")
  },
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$gte": [
          {
            "$hour": "$date"
          },
          9
        ]
      },
      {
        "$lt": [
          {
            "$hour": "$date"
          },
          17
        ]
      },
      
    ]
  }
})
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ksa4bxihYxA) to playground